# Rspec/FactoryGirl uniqueness validations in a large test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Using Rspec and FactoryGirl, if I have a factory that autoincrements a `trait` using a sequence, and in some specs if I explicitly set this trait, with a large enough test suite, sometimes random specs fail with

```
Validation failed: uniq_id has already been taken
```

The factory is defined like this:

```
factory :user { sequence(:uniq_id) {|n| n + 1000} }
```

I'm guessing this validation fails because in one place in my test suite, I generate a user like this:

```
create(:user, uniq_id: 5555)
```

And because presumably factory girl is generating more than 4,555 users over the suite, the validation is failing?

I'm attempting to avoid this problem by just turning the `uniq_id` into 55555 (larger number), so there is no interference. But is there a better solution? My `spec_helper` includes these relevant bits:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

config.after(:all) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
```

Comment: I think you can solve your problem in factory girl callbacks. For example you can check uniqueness value in `after(:build)` callback and if another user with such value exists trigger `sequence` again.

Comment: @gotva this sounds like a great solution. Can you post as an answer and with example code for the `after(:build)`? I'm not sure how to use sequence in the block and their docs don't make it clear.

Comment: @gotva figured it out actually and it worked beautifully. Thank you! Add as an answer so I can accept and give you all the points.

Comment: sorry, I don't have opportunity to test factory girl now - so I am afraid I can give incorrect code. I gave you idea, you implemented it - post the result as answer and accept it yourself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue like this in my factory (based on @gotva's suggestion in the question comments).

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:uniq_id) { |n| n + 1000 }
   # increment again if somehow invalid
   after(:build) do |obj|
     if !obj.valid? && obj.errors.keys.include?(:uniq_id)
       obj.uniq_id +=1
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me sometimes. I didn't found any explanation, but happens only with big set of data. I let someone find the explanation!

When it happens, you can declare your attribute like this (here is an example using `faker`  gem) :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    login do 
      # first attempt
      l = Faker::Internet.user_name
      while User.exists?(:login => l) do
        # Here is a loop forcing validation
        l = Faker::Internet.user_name
      end
      l   # return login
    end
  end
end
```